# Implement Google Charts into Razor Page from Blazor App

Tags: blazor, google-visualization

I want to implement a standard Google Chart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) into a Razor Page in a standard Blazor App (for example into the page FetchData.razor).

In which file do I have to implement the script part?

How do I call the script from the Razor Page?

How do I send data to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**_layout.cshtml**

```html
<body>
  ...
  <script src="pages/Index.razor.js"></script>
  ...
</body>
```

**Pages/Index.razor.js**

```js
window.onload = function () {
  google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['line'] });
}

function drawChart(json) {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);

  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    ...
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

**Pages/Index.razor**

```html
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
...
<div id="chart_div"></div>
...
```

**Pages/Index.razor.cs**
`Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper` is used to create DataTable that fits the requirements for the Google Charts.

```cs
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
...
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  string dataTable = GetDataTable().GetJson();
  await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("drawChart", dataTable);
}
```

In this case `OnAfterRenderAsync` is used to call the drawChart function, because the chartdata changes during runtime.